# Can I use only ALSA to select the sound card?

Tags: debian, audio, alsa

If I select from `alsamixer` the Nvidia sound card it doesn't work at all and I can't raise the volume of the six items (`S/PDIF`, `S/PDIF 1`, etc):
[image]

Some info:

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf3310000 irq 31
 1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xf3080000 irq 17
```

```
Kernel: 5.10.0-11-amd64 
Distro: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
```

To use the monitor speakers can I use only ALSA?

If I start `pulseaudio` I can use them.

```
# pactl list short sources
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
2   alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
5   alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra2.monitor module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
# pactl list short sinks
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
4   alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra2 module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
```

On `pasystray` I can simply select the sink `GP106 High Definition Audio Controller ...` but sometimes it doesn't work.

When PA is running if I select the `HDA nvidia` sound card with `alsamixer` is the same as before.

This is the `/etc/asound.conf` that I made:

```
defaults.pcm.card 1
defaults.ctl.card 1
```

That is for selecting the default card.

I can change the one in use it with `alsavolume-icon` but after it shows the muted icon and I can't raise the volume as for when using `alsamixer`.

Can I get it to work? Then with `asound.conf` I will make it the default card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As dirkt said you need to debug your `.asoundrc`.
Use `aplay -L` to list all PCMs defined.

With their config only stream at time is permitted.
In my case `pcm.!default "plughw:1,8"` has the right values.

While this config allow more streams:

```
pcm.nvidiamix {
    type dmix
    ipc_key 1024
    slave {
        pcm "hw:NVidia,3"
        channels 2
        #rate 48000
        period_time 0
        period_size 1024
        buffer_time 0
        buffer_size 8192
    }
    bindings.0 0
    bindings.1 1
}
pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "nvidiamix"
    hint {
        show on
        description "Default Card NVidia"
    }
}
ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card "NVidia"
}
```

You will see a new `Master` in `alsamixer` but it is pointless and you can only mute the `S/PDIF` that gives the sound.
With `Intel HDA` you can set volume level, not with Nvidia.
With the `ddcutil` package you can change the monitor settings.

Some app may not work `apulse` package may fix that.
Or you can try `pipewire` https://wiki.debian.org/PipeWire.

Comment: @dirkt can you add a volume control to that config?

Answer (score 3):

Here, ALSA provides only what the actual hardware can do. In the case of the NVidia HDA sound chip, it only provides on/off switches for each S/PDIF digital channel (which are usually associated with HDMI or DisplayPort digital display connections).

You should be able to toggle each channel on/off in `alsamixer` by pressing the <kbd>M</kbd> key, and using left/right arrow keys to move between channels. The volume sliders (adjustable with up/down arrow keys) will be presented only if the sound chip has actual mixer functionality. Display cards and other devices that pass sound in digital format only might not have analog-style mixer functionality at all, as they are often little more than "straight pipes" for standard-format digital audio data.

If you meant that you can't even see the display in your screenshot when PulseAudio is in use, try explicitly setting the sound card number, i.e. `alsamixer -c 0` and `alsamixer -c 1`.

With Debian's current default configuration, if you are using PulseAudio, running `alsamixer` without options will just show the master volume control of PulseAudio and nothing else. But if you specify the sound card number, you will still be able to access the settings provided by the ALSA driver.

PulseAudio brings in the *software mixing* capability, allowing you to adjust the volume by using the CPU to modify the digital sound data stream to make it softer or louder, or mixing sound from multiple sources into a single output, even if the stream is going to an output device that technically only accepts line-level sound data streams, like a HDMI audio channel.

PulseAudio also does *sample rate conversions* when needed: if your monitor supports only a single sample rate, the ALSA driver layer will reject attempts to play any sound data that would use a different sample rate.

Technically ALSA *could* do software mixing and sample rate conversions too, it's just that ALSA's way of adjusting software mixing usually involves editing the `.asoundrc` file, when PulseAudio allows easy dynamic reconfiguration, even while sound sources are playing. As a result, using `alsa-lib` for this purpose has fallen out of favor, and PulseAudio has essentially taken its place.

ALSA used to be divided into three main components:

- `alsa-driver`: the actual sound card drivers (now integrated into the Linux kernel)
- `alsa-lib`: a common library for using the driver, configurable using `.asoundrc` .
- `alsa-tools`: the userspace tools like `alsamixer`, `aplay`, `arecord` and others.

HDMI displays and many USB-connected sound devices only accept a set of discrete sampling frequencies, so the ability to automatically convert the sample rate whenever needed is increasingly important. This seems to be another reason why `alsa-lib` has fallen out of favor.

To select the sound card using the ALSA driver interface, you will need to specify the device either by card & device numbers (see `aplay -l` for available options) or by output device name (see `aplay -L` respectively).

The exact way to input the sound card & device numbers or the ALSA device name to an application that uses the ALSA driver interface unfortunately varies by application: some applications will accept the name only, others can use the numbers only. The command line option or configuration item name also varies by application: there is no single strongly-established convention on how you could expect it to be done.

Comment: +1 for this detailed answer. I am not sure I understand what you mean with the very last paragraph. Specification as part of the command line vs configuration menu vs config file (in which case I do agree) or the label one should use to reference the pcm/sound-device (in which case I would not agree.)

Comment: @MC68020 Mostly the former, and also the fact that some applications specifically want the name, while other (usually older) programs may accept the numbers only. When using the ALSA driver interface, you'll need to be aware that both ways exist.

Comment: Well let's acknowledge that Alsa doc. describes the "well-known" (sic) device names. :-P OK ! that does not stand for a "strongly-established convention", true !

Answer (score 2):

> To use the monitor speakers can I use only ALSA?

Most applications that use ALSA directly have a way to choose the device for output (via command-line options, or via a configuration dialog).

You can also create an [asoundrc](https://www.alsa-project.org/wiki/Asoundrc) configuration file, either system-wide ( `/etc/asound.conf`) or per user (`$HOME/.asoundrc`), where you can set the [default device](https://www.alsa-project.org/wiki/Asoundrc).

> If I select from alsamixer the nvidia sound card it doesn't work at all

Selecting a sound card inside of `alsamixer` has only the purpose to get at the mixer settings for this soundcard. It doesn't make the soundcard a default, nor does it influence anything else.

If you have Pulseaudio installed, usually you also have an asoundrc file that specifies the `pulse` pseudo-device as default, so that may conflict with what you want to do with ALSA alone.

---

Help for debugging asoundrc issues: My `~/.asoundrc` has

```
 pcm.!default "plughw:2,0"
```

to select the automatic `plughw` for card 2, as determined with `aplay -L`. You probably need card 1. Start with that single line, test if it works with `aplay` without `-D`. If it works, add the `ctl` part.

---

If your codec (sound hardware chip) has no volume control, then it has no volume control, so then you cannot change the volume.

You can put a "software volume control" in front:

```
pcm.!default "mynvidia"
ctl.!default "mynvidia"

pcm.mynvidia {
  type softvol
  slave {
    pcm "plughw:2,0"
  }
  control {
    name "Master"
    card "NVidia"
  }
}
```

And maybe you can also use the `plughw` with the symbolic card name, but I haven't tried that myself.

Comment: +1 also for this answer. Your last paragraph rightly suggest that wherever you get whatever server of whatever, don't try to bypass it. If one wants to access sound drivers more or less directly, disable the sound servers first. Most of them are likely to lock the hardware sound device anyway.

Comment: Selecting a card with `alsamixer` and changing the volume with up/down changes the volume. But I can't change the  `HDA nvidia` card volume levels.
When I select with `volumeicon-alsa` the `HDA Nvidia` card it show the mute icon and  I can't raise it. Also I made the `/etc/asound.conf` file.

Comment: (1) Yes, that's expected. (2) If the mixers for NVidia for your hardware don't allow volume change, or mute, then yes, you cannot change it. (3) Nothing of this has anything to do which card will be used to output sound. (4) If you want to actually test that you can select a card for output, find a WAV file, and use `aplay -D plughw:CARD=... yourfile.wav` with the right card identifier to try that out. `aplay -L` will show those (just put in the CARD, ignore DEV).

Comment: @dirkt With `aplay -D ...` I can play a sound. But can I make it the default output so that when  a sound is played, for example a video player, it goes through it?

Comment: You already made an asoundrc, so if that one works, `aplay` should play a sound even without `-D`. If it doesn't, there's a problem with your asoundrc.

Comment: Without `-D` doesn't work. Iis possible to make all sounds automatically use that output? And not playing them manually.

Comment: Then start debugging your asoundrc. See answer for what I use. It's also easier to start out with a per-user asoundrc.

Comment: @dirkt Looked the answer I fix it, but after reboot the `DEV` of `plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8` changed, can I something to avoid that? I have 6 `DEV`s

Comment: Also from `alsamixer` I can only mute that channel. No way to set the volume level?

Comment: With that config I got `alsamixer
ALSA lib control.c:1360:(snd_ctl_open_conf) Invalid type for CTL default definition
cannot open mixer: Invalid argument`, when opening `alsamixer`. Is there a way to make `alsa` play multiple audio streams?

Comment: @dirkt Can you add how to use the `plughw` with the symbolic card name in the answer? It seems that usually don't change anyway. And fix the volume control?